# Gitlab Omnibus not working: 502 error

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to set up Gitlab Omnibus 7.4.2 on my Ubuntu 14.10 x64 system, but when I try to access it from my computer it shows

## 502

### Gitlab is not responding

---

Please contact your administrator if your problem persists.

If this problem is still a thing and I'm not tinkering, you can access the page at http://dev.scocwa.classcoder.com/

EDIT: See my answer below.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I have tried turning it off and back on again :)

Comment: Could you provide a few more details about which steps you took to set up Gitlab? How did you install it? Were there any errors during or after install? How are you going about trying to access the program after installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems 512MB of RAM isn't enough for GitLab. I've added 1GB of swap and it seems to work now.

Comment: My virtual machine has 6GB Ram and I´m getting the same error...